# HIbernate + a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an object with the parent and child relationship. 
I am getting an error when I try to fetch a unique Id from one table.

```
public Integer getLoanStatusSql(String id){
    Session session = getSession();
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select loan_status from loans where loan_id = :loanId");
    query.setParameter("loanId", id);
    session.clear();
    ***Object result = query.uniqueResult();***
    if(result != null) {
        return ((BigDecimal) (result)).intValue();          
    } else {
        return null;
    }    }
```

***Object result = query.uniqueResult();*** Line causes this issue.

```
Parent Class A{
 private String loanid;
 Child class b;
 }

  Child Class B{...... }
```

One to many relationship between A and B, so corresponding hbm.xml are included.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Need the hbm files to help you.

Comment: How does your getSession() look like?

Answer (score 0):

Didnt not see the issue after merging the code with main branch, not sure what change was made.

I didnt not make any change to fix it.